# SQL Server: Inconsistent results of IF statement

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

I am doing a data migration and I am currently implementing a reverse-script for our worst case scenario. I might be a little bit tired now but I can´t get my head around this thing - so maybe you can help.

I have the following SQL:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N'FileId' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'[FileData]'))
AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'FileData' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'FileDataId')
BEGIN
    SELECT 1;
    --ALTER TABLE [FileData] ADD [FileId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL
    --ALTER TABLE [FileData] DROP CONSTRAINT PK_FileData

    --UPDATE [FileData] SET [FileData].[FileId] = [File].[FileId] 
    --FROM [FileData] INNER JOIN [File] on [FileData].FileDataId = [File].FileData

    --ALTER TABLE [FileData] ALTER COLUMN [FileId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
    --ALTER TABLE [FileData] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_FileData PRIMARY KEY (FileId)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 0;
END
```

Running the query above will consistently return a 0 - which is correct, since the `FileName` column does exist and the `FileDataId` does not. So far so good.

When I remove the first `select` statement and uncomment the alter and update code. I get the error:

> Invalid column name 'FileDataId'

Query I run after uncommenting

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N'FileId' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'[FileData]'))
AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'FileData' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'FileDataId')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [FileData] ADD [FileId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL
    ALTER TABLE [FileData] DROP CONSTRAINT PK_FileData

    UPDATE [FileData] SET [FileData].[FileId] = [File].[FileId] 
    FROM [FileData] INNER JOIN [File] on [FileData].FileDataId = [File].FileData

    ALTER TABLE [FileData] ALTER COLUMN [FileId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [FileData] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_FileData PRIMARY KEY (FileId)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 0;
END
```

My question:
How come I consistently get the same `false` result from the IF-statement but when I uncomment the code in the `true`-clause it suddenly gets entered. Am I completely missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server wants to *compile* the entire batch before it *executes* it. It fails to compile it because the column doesn't exist, and so it never gets as far as executing the `IF` statement.

You have to use [dynamic SQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) so that it doesn't attempt to compile the statements referencing the column until after you've verified its existence.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N'FileId' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'[FileData]'))
AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'FileData' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'FileDataId')
BEGIN
    EXEC('ALTER TABLE [FileData] ADD [FileId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL')
    EXEC('ALTER TABLE [FileData] DROP CONSTRAINT PK_FileData')

    EXEC('UPDATE [FileData] SET [FileData].[FileId] = [File].[FileId]
    FROM [FileData] INNER JOIN [File] on [FileData].FileDataId = [File].FileData')

    EXEC('ALTER TABLE [FileData] ALTER COLUMN [FileId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL')
    EXEC('ALTER TABLE [FileData] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_FileData PRIMARY KEY (FileId)')
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 0;
END
```

Comment: Naturally, it´s the UPDATE-statment that is the issue. I completely forgot that I had that statement in there. That is also the only statement I need to execute in child scope - as such:
EXEC ('UPDATE [FileData] SET [FileData].[FileId] = [File].[FileId] FROM [FileData] INNER JOIN [File] on [FileData].FileDataId = [File].FileData')

Thank you so much!