# Why does SQL evaluate statements in the true section of an if exists construct, even if the `if exists` returns false?

Tags: sql, sql-server

(I apologize in advance for the awful explanation, but if you run the queries below you should see what I mean!)

Why does MSSQL evaluate statements in the `true` section of an `if exists` construct, even if the `if exists` returns false, causing errors?

For example, in the two queries below, the first checks if a table exists (which it does) and also checks if that table has certain columns. For some reason, running this query throws the following errors because the table exists but the columns don't.

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Invalid column name 'colB'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Invalid column name 'colC'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Invalid column name 'colA'.
```

The behavior I expected here was for SQL to just move onto the `falsepart` of the construct, without throwing errors. (As it does with the next query).

However, the second script (which is identical, bar table names) executes successfully. This is because the table the query is searching for does not exist.

```
--Scripts to setup the example.
CREATE DATABASE TEST 
GO
USE TEST
GO
CREATE TABLE t1 (colD VARCHAR(255)) --Create a table with the correct name, but incorrect column names.
GO

--This query fails, because t1 exists, even though the columns in t1 don't.
IF EXISTS (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 't1' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('colA','colB','colC'))
BEGIN
    SELECT colA FROM t1 WHERE colB = 0 AND colC = 1
END
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT 'FALSE'
END

GO

--This query executes ok, because t2 does not exist.
IF EXISTS (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 't2' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('colA','colB','colC'))
BEGIN
    SELECT colA FROM t2 WHERE colB = 0 AND colC = 1
END
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT 'FALSE'
END
```

Is anybody able to explain to me why the first query errors, when the second query runs fine?

So far, I've only managed to test this in Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Comment: It's failing to *compile* the batch, it's not even getting to a point of *running* the code. Consider, in C#, if you have a load of reflection calls to check whether a particular class contains a particular method. You can't just have those checks in an `if` and then, within the body of the `if` have a line that *calls* that method on an instance of the class - for the same reason - it will fail to *compile*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I understand what you mean, but if it fails to compile the batch because *some* of the objects don't exist, why does the second query run find when *none* of the object exist?

Comment: The situation with the table is slightly odder, but it's because of [deferred name resolution](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686(v=sql.105).aspx) (one place where SQL will, deliberately, postpone compilation until the statement is reached)

Comment: Deleted my anser cause I can se @Damien_The_Unbeliever has answered. Post it as an actual answer so we can rep you :)

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen - I'm tempted to close as duplicate with [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18657458/15498), although specific mention of deferred name resolution for table names isn't present there.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Could you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Apologies. I'd always intended to come back and turn it into an answer "when I had time", but it fell off the back of my mental "To do" list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the first part of this question. Assuming familiarity with a language (such as C#) which has some form of runtime type inspection (e.g. Reflection).

Assume you have code like this:

```
SomeType t = GetSomeTypeFromSomewhere();
if(t.GetType().GetMethod("FunTimes")!=null)
{
     t.FunTimes();
}
```

And assume that `SomeType` *doesn't* contain a public method called `FunTimes`. Even though I've written a guard around trying to invoke the `FunTimes` method, I get an error. And, specifically, I get a *compile* time error - the C# compiler cannot even generate the code, let alone get close to running the code, obtaining the result from `GetMethod()` and deciding not to run the code within the nested block.

To switch back to your code, the exact same type of analysis applies here:

```
IF EXISTS (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 't1' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('colA','colB','colC'))
BEGIN
    SELECT colA FROM t1 WHERE colB = 0 AND colC = 1
END
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT 'FALSE'
END
```

SQL Server tries to compile this batch and fails. It never executes the code, so it never gets to the point of deciding which branch (`IF` or `ELSE`) to take.

So, if all of the above is true, why then does the second piece of code work? That's because of an particular feature of T-SQL called [Deferred Name Resolution](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686(v=sql.105).aspx). Basically, there's a special rule that applies when the object that's missing is a *table* (or view, since the two are indistinguishable until the object can be found). In that specific instance, SQL Server will not immediately signal a compilation error.

Under deferred name resolution, execution will start and, if something causes schema changes (such as by adding the missing table/view), this causes the system to recompile the remainder of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are evaluating the results wrong (AND it is not your fault IMHO).

EXISTS part returns FALSE in both cases. However, the SQL query parser is funny, it parses the inside expressions and gives the error before execution of the statements, only if column(s) is missing, it doesn't give an error if the table is missing.

In your first query where it seems to be evaluating to TRUE, try changing table name to something like t2 and you would see it runs and evaluates to FALSE in both.